# Inserting value in between an array in action script3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am inserting a value on 3 position the value is being inserted but somehow while copying the rest part it does not copy the last point. The size of an array is not increasing. Can anyone tell me how to add new elements in an array in between.

```
for(indexpoint=0;indexpoint<3;indexpoint++) 
{           
    temp.points[indexpoint].x = intpoints[indexpoint].x+this.x;
    temp.points[indexpoint].y = intpoints[indexpoint].y+this.y; 
}

temp.points[3].x = (intpoints[2].x+intpoints[3].x)/2+this.x;
temp.points[3].y = (intpoints[2].y+intpoints[3].y)/2+this.y;

for(indexpoint=3;indexpoint<intpoints.length;indexpoint++)
{           
    temp.points[indexpoint+1].x = intpoints[indexpoint].x+this.x;
    temp.points[indexpoint+1].y = intpoints[indexpoint].y+this.y;       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To insert new elements in an array, you can use the method `splice()`, but first, you have to create the object that you want to add (it looks like a `Point` in your code):

```
const point:Point = new Point();
point.x = intpoints[2].x+intpoints[3].x)/2+this.x;
point.y = intpoints[2].y+intpoints[3].y)/2+this.y;

temp.points.splice(3, 0, point);
```

You could also do this:

```
temp.points.length = 0;

for each (var point:Point in intpoints) {
    temp.points.add(point.clone().add(this));
}

const newPoint:Point = new Point();
newPoint.x = intpoints[2].x+intpoints[3].x)/2+this.x;
newPoint.y = intpoints[2].y+intpoints[3].y)/2+this.y;
temp.points.splice(3, 0, newPoint);
```

Comment: I did this,now what happens it duplicates the last point three times at the end of the array.

Comment: What is `temp`, and are you sure that `intpoints.length === temp.points.length` before the first loop? Why don't you start with an empty array that you fill with your values?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `splice` function?

```
array.splice( positionToInsertIn, 0, newValue );
```

Comment: I did this,now what happens it duplicates the last point three times at the end of the array